# Tap in UIWebView to Hide Keyboard

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios

I'd lik to have the same behavior in my app as Safari has. In Safari when the keyboard is visible a tap in an area outside the editing field will cause the keyboard to hide.
But with a `UIWebView` in my own app that's not the case by default. So how can I get this behavior to my app?

I tried to add a `UIGestureRecognizer` but it fires never or always (depending on `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:`). So I tried to override the `sendEvent:` in the `UIWindow`. But that also has the problem that I always get the tap. Even when tapping on e.g. the text that's being edited. So no text selection is possible.

--edit

I just discovered that this behaviour is not default in Safari. Only on the google search page it's this way. So there must be a JavaScript solution for this problem.

Comment: Try this:
[Writing iOS4 Code to Hide the iPhone Keyboard](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Writing_iOS_4_Code_to_Hide_the_iPhone_Keyboard). It worked for me =)

Comment: you need to use `resignFirstResponder`

Answer (score 4):

hide the keyboard when the webView is scrolled:

```
self.webView.scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Answer (score -3):

Subclass the web view and override

> -(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
>   Goog luck.

Comment: Subclasses of UIView do not get that message.

Comment: Yes it does. May be you should do some test and research before you give and negative. An UIWebView it dose'nt

Comment: Well I implemented it and it didn't. But anyway if it did. First of all you shouldn't subclass a UIWebView and second it does not solve the problem.

Comment: "The UIWebView class should not be subclassed."  This will probably cause your app to be rejected.